# Difference in meaning : Rude of you to say vs Rude of you saying

Tags: meaning

> 1. Don't you think that it's a little rude of you saying that?
> 2. Don't you think that it's a little rude of you to say that?

What is the difference in meaning between them? and Are they all grammatically correct?

Comment: #1 is perfectly "idiomatic", in that it wouldn't be noticed as "unusual" *in that exact utterance* (which is sufficiently complex that most native speakers won't be paying much attention to minor syntax shortcomings by the end of it). But it's far less common than #2, and strictly speaking it's probably "ungrammatical" anyway. Compare the noticeably "strange" ***It's nice of you saying so*** with the perfectly natural ***It's nice of you to say so*** as a modest response to a compliment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can feel "nice of you saying so" sounds strange, but as for sentence 1, it seems quite natural, not strange even at all. By the way, is "it" referring to "saying that" in sentence 1?

Comment: Where do we draw the line? *It's raining* is a clear-cut example of "existential **it**" (doesn't refer to anything specifically identifiable). Presumably we'd all say the same about *It's late* or *It's dark*, but what about *It's too late to go out* or *It's too kind of you to say that*? I speak English perfectly well, and my degree includes linguistics, but even I can't answer all those kind of questions. Or perhaps I should say that the only sensible answer is *Don't ask that! It won't help you learn English!*